# Exchange compromise affected company - should we 100% change administrator password?

Tags: passwords, exchange

We host exchange on premise (exchange 2013).  We believe following MS's guides and guidelines that we were compromised regarding the [exchange zero days hack](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/microsoft-fixes-actively-exploited-exchange-zero-day-bugs-patch-now/).  We did find some .aspx files that did not appear to be from us in our inetpub directory.  From [the article listed](https://us-cert.cisa.gov/ncas/alerts/aa21-062a) we followed this to find these aspx files:

> To determine possible webshell activity, administrators should search
> for aspx files in the following paths:
>
> \inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\ (any .aspx file under this folder or
> sub folders) <exchange install path>\FrontEnd\HttpProxy\ecp\auth
> (any file besides TimeoutLogoff.aspx) <exchange install
> path>\FrontEnd\HttpProxy\owa\auth\ (any file or modified file that is
> not part of a standard install) <exchange install
> path>\FrontEnd\HttpProxy\owa\auth\Current\ (any aspx file in this
> folder or subfolders) <exchange install
> path>\FrontEnd\HttpProxy\owa\auth<folder with version number>\ (any
> aspx file in this folder or subfolders)

We have [patched the server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58392) immediately and ran the [MSERT tool that microsoft has released](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/intelligence/safety-scanner-download) across all of our servers.  We also took some additional security precautions like blocking the IP ranges listed from the article above on our firewall, as mentioned in the article:

> Volexity has seen attackers leverage the following IP addresses.
> Although these are tied to virtual private servers (VPSs) servers and
> virtual private networks (VPNs), responders should investigate these
> IP addresses on their networks and act accordingly:
>
> 103.77.192[.]219
> 104.140.114[.]110
> 104.250.191[.]110
> 108.61.246[.]56
> 149.28.14[.]163
> 157.230.221[.]198
> 167.99.168[.]251
> 185.250.151[.]72
> 192.81.208[.]169
> 203.160.69[.]66
> 211.56.98[.]146
> 5.254.43[.]18
> 5.2.69[.]14
> 80.92.205[.]81
> 91.192.103[.]43

All other servers were scanned and we are also using a tool called [SentinelOne](https://www.sentinelone.com/) on all of our servers.

I'm not a network administrator but wanted to know if it is required to change our administrator password.

What is the probability that an attacker could somehow get this password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Successful exploitation of these vulnerabilities allows an unauthenticated attacker to execute arbitrary code on vulnerable Exchange Servers, enabling the attacker to gain persistent system access, as well as access to files and mailboxes on the server and to credentials stored on that system. Successful exploitation may additionally enable the attacker to compromise trust and identity in a vulnerable network.

This is an excerpt from your link https://us-cert.cisa.gov/ncas/alerts/aa21-062a and given this I cannot think of a reason to not change administrator passwords as a minimum and immediately. As it says, credentials were potentially jeopardized and if these belonged to a domain admin (and not local admin on the exchange box) this could lead to compromise of the entire domain.

I am not a lawyer, but I do of course advise to follow whatever legalisation and company processes are set in place for a potential breach.